# Can I use another memory than Apple for my iMac?

Tags: upgrade, mac, ddr2

I'd like to put 8Gb RAM in my iMac, and take out the 2Gb installed.
The price by Apple being too excessive, I'd like to know if it's possible to build a "normal" RAM in like Samsung or Corsair, etc... Is there any consequence of doing so?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should say my iMac is from early 2009, I guess with DDR3 memory, probably 2x1Gb.

Comment: You can find out the memory type by clicking on Apple Menu>About this Mac > More Info > scroll down to memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to build a "normal" RAM in like Samsung or Corsair, etc...

Yes

> Is there any consequence of doing so?

you save money.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special about the RAM that Apple uses, as long as the memory mets the same requirements, you'll be fine...

I would suggest ensuring this by using either Crucial or Kingston memory, and not getting generic memory.... Both companies have memory configurators that will give you the equivalent part numbers that you'll need when ordering memory...

Apple does not typically use custom hardware that started to stop in the late 90's....  Today, they use mainly off the shelve equipment.  The only custom hardware would be the motherboard, and even that is probably a semi-custom job from Intel.

What makes the hardware different is simply it's scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the real good explanation to it. I like it. I give the right answer to "Neal" thought, just cause I like the humoristic part... and he was first!